# How to get a rout information with trafic flow information included for a past date?

Tags: api, azure-maps

I am trying to use Azure Maps API. It will be nice to have route information which should include the locations of course and a speed profile. As you can understand speed profile is not an east one. Free flow speed profile is ok. But we want to simulate real-world conditions meaning that we want to select date and time of departure to get accurate speed information as close to as possible to a real world traffic influence.

Is there any feature that Azure provide this? If not, which API can provide this

I don't have any code at this moment to show since ı don't know which API to use.

Answer (score 1):

Historical traffic data is not currently available in Azure Maps but is being investigated as a potential future feature.